# How to format a string into a shape?

Tags: python, formatting, shapes

I want to be able to print a string and format it into a shape. In the code here it formats into a right triangle, but I wanna do other shapes too. The problem is I can't get the string to truncate at each line and continue on, it simply loops at the first character.

this is what it looks like

```
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhh
hhhhh
hhh
h
```

but I want it to look like this

```
hellowor
ldhowar
eyout
oday
?
```

I've been struggling to wrap my head around this concept a lot lately, I can't seem to loop functions within functions properly. I think I'm probably missing some key part of knowledge for indexes or for loops that's stopping me. But if you could show me here, I might be able to learn a bit more about it. I've tried googling this issue to no avail. I appreciate any help.

Here's my code thus far:

```
text = ('hello world how are you today?')

def word():
    for c in text:
        return c

def triangle(i, t = 0):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        print '' * (t + 1) + word() * (i * 2 - 1)
        return triangle (i - 1, t + 1)
triangle (8)
```

edit:

the other thing I added was this:

```
def triangle(i, t = 0):
if i == 0:
    return 0
else:
    for c in text:
        print '' * (t + 1) + word() * (i * 2 - 1)

    return triangle (i - 1, t + 1)
```

but it yields the same problem, where by it only prints the first letter from 'text'.

How do I loop through each letter?

Comment: When you `return`, it kills the function and gives you the returned value, so your `word` function will only ever return the first `c` in `text`, which is `"h"`

Comment: I'm not clear on your desired result: you want lines of 8, 7, 5, 4, and leftover characters?  Why/how did you skip 6?  Your meaningless variables names and lack of structure comments make this hard to follow.  Also, you seem to have stripped out white space somewhere along the way, but I don't see your code doing it.

Comment: @Prune I typed the second one out manually because I can't get the program to do it haha. That's why it skipped 6, human error.

I basically want to define a triangle of x length (in this case its 8, but it could be any) and then print a string within that triangle, so that each line is truncated by the width of the triangle as it goes down. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ryugie What's the alternative to return that would cycle through all of the chars in the string? More to the point would that alternative work with the rest of the program to produce the desired result? Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely with the rest of the code?

Comment: @ryugie I changed return to print but I get this error
     'File "triangle.py", line 16, in <module>
        triangle (9)
      File "triangle.py", line 13, in triangle
         print '' * (t + 1) + word() * (i * 2 - 1)
     TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int''

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  The basic answer is that you're making this too complicated.  Start at the front of the string with your initial row; pass the remainder to a recursive call.  Don't bother to take individual characters out of the string: just grab the subset you need.

Note that this has *two* base cases: Either **size** hits 0, or you run out of message before that.

```
def triangle(message, size):
    # Size = 0: we're done; ran out of rows
    if size == 0:
        return
    # Not enough message left: print it all
    if size >= len(message):
        print message
    # print "size" characters and go to next line
    else:
        print message[:size]
        triangle(message[size:], size-1)


text = "hello world how are you today?"
triangle(text, 8)
print ""
triangle(text, 7)
```

Output:

```
hello wo
rld how
 are y
ou to
day?

hello w
orld h
ow ar
e yo
u t
od
a
```

---

STRING SLICES

The general form is

```
str[start : end : step]
```

This gets you the substring from str[start] through str[end-1], inclusive.  If you omit any of the arguments, the defaults are

```
start = 0
end = -1 (through the end of the string)
step = 1
```

Since we rarely have regular skips through a string, the **step** argument is almost always defaulted to 1.

Comment: Wow awesome. Thanks heaps! Can I ask you: what are these doing [:size] and [size:]....You don't have to explain it yourself, but if you could tell me the name of this particular thing in pyhton I can go look it up myself. Thanks again!

Comment: @elliotholder - It's just slicing, like in lists (Section 3.1.4): https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html